# How to speed up view for large documents and a lot of functionalities based on AngularJS 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, web

In our SPA application, built with AngularJS 1.5, customers can view structured text documents. Often they are large like 25000 DOM nodes or so. Document structure can hardly be reduced.

When we try to bind such heavy document (HTML) to the view it freezes for a while.
Users also see some performance problems in the browser while working with the document text as the application has lots of functionalities for this.
We have to provide the entire documents to our users because they want to work with the whole content at the same time.
We are also not allowed to drop any of functionalities. Except performance, UX is fine now.

We think it will help if we build something like a virtual scroll, where only visible part of the document will be in the DOM.
Another thing to consider is rewriting this particular view (document view) with another framework / library. AJS 2.x is on the horizon.
We have also React, Vue.js and ..?

Do you have any other ideas? Do you have some experience with large documents and frameworks like AngularJS?
Will AJS 2.x be better than AJS 1.x or React or something else?

Comment: is your Dom structure contains hidden elements ? prefer to use `ng-if` instead `ng-show` in that case

Comment: @ArnaudGueras We made a lot of improvements in our code before, including all guidelines helping developers with AJS 1.x
We also keep track to the AJS 1.x changes at the same time they came out and try to figure out how we could use them in our case.
But it's not enough. We still have problems with performance and functionalities will be growing.

Comment: Virtual scroll is good if you have lots of ngRepeat items. check this repo: http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=8

Comment: @MuliYulzary Right now we have one piece of content, but for virtual scroll, we think about splitting up the content to small parts as it's structured.

Comment: I think virtual scroll is the way to go, because it will free up memory when content that's not on screen wont be available in the dom. I recently found Ionic's collection-repeat, so it may be usefull as an inspiration (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/).

Comment: @VadiemJanssens Do you have any idea how to implement that functionality when our chunks have different heights? I have legal document, which I would like to split by articles / paragraphs and each of them could be different height. It's not possible to reserve exacly calculated space before and after the visible part of the document.

Comment: I think @MuliYulzary mentioned a plugin called `angular-vs-repeat`. It supports elements with variable heights (http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=6). Maybe this will help?